# Deal with tags containing colons in Groovy Markup Teamplate Engine

Tags: templates, groovy

I would like to use the Groovy Markup Template Engine so that the final result is the following:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="cxf02" ac:name="warning" ac:schema-version="1">ERROR</ac:structured-macro>
```

The basic code that I am running is the following:

```
TemplateConfiguration config = new TemplateConfiguration()
MarkupTemplateEngine engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config)
Template template = engine.createTemplate("""
<!-- I don't know what to put here -->
    """)
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>()                      
Writable output = template.make(model)
println(output)
```

I guess colons and dashes should be escaped, or something like that.
I could not find the answer on the groovy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've found the answer right after posting the question here:

just surround the tag with "", so the template should be

```
"ac:structured-macro"("ac:macro-id":"cxf02", "ac:name":"warning", "ac:schema-version":"1", "ERROR")
```